# How to map numbers utilizing array function

Tags: functions

I would have thought this would be simple, however, I'm having a hard time with it. I have this function and I'm having a hard time mapping numbers. I have a spreadsheet that I import with WP All Import and utilize this function for a variety of other fields that are not numbers and it works great.

In example, other fields where I use this function is for something like `'Gasoline' => 'Gas'` and it maps "Gasoline" to the "Gas" category without any issues, however when using only numbers (2, 4, 6 etc) as seen below, it won't map it to the "X Passenger" category that I have in the database. I hope I'm explaining this appropriately.

Anybody have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
function seating_translate_data_sample( $data ) {

    if (empty($data)) {
        echo "Not Specified";
    }

    $map = array(
        '2'  => '2 Passenger',
        '4'  => '4 Passenger',
        '6'  => '6 Passenger',
        '8'  => '8 Passenger',
        '10' => '10 Passenger',
    );

    foreach ( $map as $partial_match => $mapped_value ) {
        if ( stristr( $data, $partial_match ) ) {
            return $mapped_value;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/368059/edit) to show us some of the `$data` that's causing you problems.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: Hi @PatJ, does my revised question help some?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that `$data` is being treated as an integer, and therefore your `stristr` is returning false.

Try explicitly casting `$data` as a string:

```
if ( stristr( strval( $data ), $partial_match ) ) {
            return $mapped_value;
        }
```